# How do I permanently install an Xcode project on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to install an Xcode project to my iPhone permanently without jailbreaking or getting the Paid Apple Enterprise Development License.

I was able to find a process to turn an xcode project into a .ipa file
but getting the .ipa file to my phone is where the issue lies.
I know I can just run the Xcode project on my iPhone but then it disappears after a week.
the same happens when using cydia impactor to install the .ipa.
I tried installing the file using Apple comparator 2 but it crashes when the downloading process is 75% through.

Comment: Why would you not use the paid version?

Comment: Trying to find all the possible options before doing that

Comment: Think this is help full.
https://ionicframework.com/blog/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5QW1p-7mEM